# listing items in list view.getting exception

Tags: android, list, listview

In my application i'm retriving files from sd card.and listing it in listview.
while listing m getting an exception fatal execption. what should i do.please help me.i'm using android2.2.same code is running on 2.3

below is code-

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        //i=getIntent();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "gallery" //folder name
        );
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        list = getSD();
        lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));//here i'm getting exeception
        Log.d("LOG", "FIRE !!!! " );  

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

                i=new Intent();
                i.putExtra("file","string");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }


        });
    }
```

exception-

```
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.zproject/com.my.zproject.ImportFile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.my.zproject.ImportFile.onCreate(ImportFile.java:38)
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

Comment: Post getSD() function ...

Comment: ohh..thank you so much.actuly i forgot to change name of xml file.

Comment: Check line 38 in your source file. It appears that whatever object is being used there is causing the error (from `02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.my.zproject.ImportFile.onCreate(ImportFile.java:38)`). I would guess at R.id.listview not being defined in R.layout.activity_main however without line numbers or activity_main.xml I could not say for certain

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:27:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at com.my.zproject.ImportFile.onCreate(ImportFile.java:38)
```

There is a `NullPointerException` in your `ImportFile` class in your method `onCreate(...)` at line **38**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the activity_main.xml. Please check for the corretc file name / variable name.